# Sierpinski triangle formula: How to take into account for $0^{th}$ power?

Tags: geometry, fractals

The formula to count Sierpinski triangle is $3^{k-1}$ .It is good if you don't take the event when $k=0$.But how can you write a more precise formula that takes the $k=0$ into account which gives $3^{-1}$? Just to note, I did figure out the equation myself as I learned it to write a program although the equation is available online.I am doing it purely for fun and out of curiosity, no homework question.

**Add-on**:

I tried to draw a tree to find the relation but still the nodes start to show pattern from level 2.[image]

Comment: What does "count the Sierpinski triangle" mean?

Comment: number of triangle.I'm making a binary tree of it and will soon upload that too.

Comment: Um, tack on the conditional that sierpinski triangle has a positive integer of degree.  Do you worry if k is fractional?  Irrational?

Comment: So that means we cannot imagine an event when we don't have any triangle?If k=0, shouldn't that be 0?The number of triangle since we are not doing any iteration?There has to be a way I believe.

Comment: It's perfectly possible that the formula is "$3^{k-1}$ when $k\ge1$ and $1$ when $k=0$". Math happens.

Comment: Yes that would be then conditional, thanks!I took it for literal sense.Give it in answer section so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want a formula to count the number $n$ of triangles that remain at level $k$ in the standard [trema construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle#Removing_triangles) of the Sierpinski triangle. If we say that level one is the initial triangle, then that leads to a sequence of images that looks like so:

[image]

We can then clearly see your formula: $n=3^{k-1}$. (Recall that $3^0=1$, so that $k=1$ yields the correct result.) This depends, however, on where you choose to start counting. I would personally prefer to call the initial triangle level zero but, really, this is somewhat arbitrary.

One other comment: I'm not sure why you're using an unbalanced *binary* tree to model this situation. It seems to me that a balanced ternary tree (where each node has three children) would be more natural.

Comment: I'm putting information in inorder binary search tree traversal that visits left child first to input information and I'm trying to draw a relationship between each level and and k.I was saying that level zero would give 3^0-1, which is 3^-1. But your explanation  is spot on though.